# awk extract data 3 days old from log and put to new file

Tags: bash, awk

I need extract 3 days old logs from one file and put to new file.

I trying using awk (maybe is other way?)

```
TZ_START=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d'now-3 days') 
awk -F, '{if($5 >= '$TZ_START') print}' < access.log > access3.log
```

but unfortunately is not working :/ access3.log is empty and don't know why.

Sample log file:

```
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-10T15:19:00 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-13T15:19:24 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-14T15:12:35 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-18T15:13:43 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-19T15:15:43 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-23T15:13:17 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-08-24T15:12:21 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This question is different, I dind't find answer under pointing link.

Comment: Why did you put a `python` tag on this question?

Comment: because i wondering if is possible do in python